# How to stop recording webcam video using Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video-capture

I have a function that starts recording from the webcam and this function is called when the user clicks on a button.

The function is as follows :

```
private function buttonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    addChild(videoCamera);  
    trace("Button clicked!");
    if (camera.muted) {
    trace("Camera Muted");
        Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
        camera.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);
    } else {
        startCamera();
    }

}
```

the function `startCamera()` is as follows :

```
private function startCamera():void {
    // here are all the quality and performance settings that we suggest
    camera.setMode(160, 120, 12, false);
    camera.setQuality(0, 75);
    camera.setKeyFrameInterval(24);
    microphone.rate = 11;
    microphone.setSilenceLevel(0);
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo");

    // get status information from the NetConnection object
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ncOnStatus); 
}
```

I tried to write function which stops recording. To do that I wrote a function

```
private function buttonClickHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
     stopCamera();
}
```

which wraps a function to close the `NetConnection.`

```
private function stopCamera():void {
     nc.close();
}
```

However, when I click this second button, the connection to the server is broken (Red5 Media Server running on Ubuntu 12.04, the previous recording is discarded and a new recording starts.

I want the previous recording to be saved, and the recording to stop.

Please help.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you create a NetStream to send the video to the server.  Are you doing this in the ncOnStatus handler function?

Comment: Can you show us the content of `ncOnStatus()` ? I suspect that this method is written in a manner that it automatically open a stream if none is open.